# What types inherit from ICollection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, icollection

I don't know why I'm having such trouble with Google today. I was wondering what types (if any) inherit from the ICollection interface. It's important that I push multiple entities into an instance of an ICollection before I save to the DB, but I don't know which type I should push them into specifically.

Update: 
The question was answered, but I want to make sure I word it in a not so confusing way (third attempt). More specifically, I need a specific type that inherits from ICollection. I'm using entity framework and the entity classes contain virtual properties of type ICollection. I want to update the relating entities by just updating that one property on the main entity. But that means I'd need to push all instances of the relating entity into an ICollection first. However it's not clear to me which types inherit from ICollection.

Comment: *I don't know which type I should push them into specifically* Is a totally different question than *What types inherit from ICollection?* Not that it's answerable with this level of detail though.

Comment: Use List<T> as described in my answer

Comment: Ohh I thought Lists only inherited from IEnumerable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a List object, that is typically the easiest to deal with.

The code for that should look something like this

```
var entities = new List<EntityType> { entity1, entity2 };
```

or

```
var entities = new List<EntityType>();
entities.add(entity1);
entities.add(entity2);
```

Here are the ICollection remarks for your reference:

The `ICollection<T>` interface is the base interface for classes in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

The `ICollection<T>` interface extends `IEnumerable<T>`

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `IList<T>` are more specialized interfaces that extend `ICollection<T>`. A `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation is a collection of key/value pairs, like the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class. A `IList<T>` implementation is a collection of values, and its members can be accessed by index, like the `List<T>` class.

If neither the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface nor the `IList<T>` interface meet the requirements of the required collection, derive the new collection class from the `ICollection<T>` interface instead for more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a premade list of these types for your perusing pleasure. However, you can easily use Reflection to find out for yourself:

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(int))
                       .GetTypes()
                       .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name == "ICollection"))
                       .ToArray();

foreach (var type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
}
```

It would include such types as `Array`, `List`, `Queue`, `Dictionary`, and all the other traditional collection types.

(Note: Not all the types listed will be publically accessible, nor will many of them be advisable for general purpose use.)

Answer (score 0):

IList for instance ->

public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:
Actually you can find the answer under the "Remarks" section here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx